# how to cancel the docker container expose port

Tags: docker, dockerfile

- I docker pull a official image from dockerHUB.
- when the docker container run up,
- use `docker ps -a` to check, found the `PORTS` column show some ports, such as:

```sh
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE    PORTS                                                        NAMES
07d3eea2018c   consul   8300-8302/tcp, 8500/tcp, 8301-8302/udp, 8600/tcp, 8600/udp   xxxx
```

**I just want `8500` port, so how to remove or cancel other ports? THANKS!**

Comment: Unless you explicitly publish a port with a `docker run -p` option, having an exposed port doesn't really have any visible effect.  Is there any specific effect you're trying to avoid, beyond it being included in the `docker ps` diagnostics?

Comment: @David Maze It really has no visible effect. I just want to remove from `docker ps` show.